# Return multiple categories in a single row & single column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of stores that sell to multiple categories and I'm looking to return a single row for each store, with the categories listed in one cell.

**My table:**

| store | category |
| --- | --- |
| a | clothing |
| b | supplies |
| c | food |
| a | supplies |
| a | food |
| b | clothing |

**What I'm looking for:**

| store | category |
| --- | --- |
| a | clothing, food, supplies |
| b | clothing, supplies |
| c | food |

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select store, string_agg(category, ', ') category
from your_table
group by store
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly